# What is the most stable globular protein?

Tags: proteins, protein-folding, protein-structure

What is the most thermodynamically stable globular protein?

I am looking for a small (ideally less than 50kDa) soluble globular protein motif which folds easily/reliably and is known to be extremely stable and resistant to unfolding once folded.  Also very resistant to proteolysis and degradation.

Any ideas?

Comment: ubitquitin is very stable, you could double check, but my supervisor was saying that people initially thought it wasn't a protein because it was so heat resistant

Comment: [RNAse A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anfinsen's_dogma) was used to prove that a protein's structural information was stored in its sequence by unfolding it and refolding it, so it must be pretty stable. I've also worked with Bee Venom PLA2, which has 5 disulfide bonds. It's so stable, I've left solutions out on the bench over the weekend and the activity wasn't harmed at all. I've conjugated the protein with peptides and/or oligosaccharides with minimal activity loss. I've iodinated the protein under harsh conditions and retained 25% activity.

Comment: After I left the lab, another student has been able to pass Bee Venom PLA2 through an HPLC column with an acetonitrile and dilute TFA gradient ( the same kind you'd use for small molecules ) and recover the enzyme with full activity. It's really stable. As for MOST stable, that's probably a thermodynamics problem. These are just my anecdotal experiences with a very stable enzyme.